# React testing library - warning test was not wrapped in act(...)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-testing-library

When using the `react-testing-library` to test my component, I get the warning

`Warning: An update to ManageAuthorPage inside a test was not wrapped in act(...).  When testing, code that causes React state updates should be wrapped into act(...):`

Here is my test - it passes, but the warning is displayed:

```
it("should display error message when creatingAuthor throws error", async () => {
  const errorMessage = "Error saving";

  const routerHistory = createMemoryHistory();
  const props = {
    createAuthor: jest.fn().mockRejectedValue(new Error(errorMessage)),
    history: routerHistory,
    author: {},
    authors: [],
    loadAuthors: jest.fn().mockResolvedValue(),
  };
  const { getByText, getByLabelText } = render(
    <Router history={routerHistory}>
      <ManageAuthorPage {...props} />
    </Router>
  );

  fireEvent.change(getByLabelText("Name"), { target: { value: "New Name" } });
  fireEvent.click(getByText("Save"));

  await waitForElement(() => getByText(errorMessage));
});
```

Here is the code snippet of the parent component that handles saving

```
function handleSave(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    if (!isFormValid()) {
      return;
    }
    createAuthor(author)
      .then(() => {
        toast.success("Author created");
        history.push("/authors");
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        setErrors({ ...errors, onSave: error.message });
          });

  }
```

And the child component that renders the save Button

```
function AuthorForm({ author, onChange, errors = {}, onSave, onCancel }) {
  return (
    <form onSubmit={onSave}>
      {errors.onSave && (
        <div className="alert alert-danger" role="alert">
          {errors.onSave}
        </div>
      )}
      <TextInput
        name="name"
        label="Name"
        value={author.name}
        onChange={onChange}
        error={errors.name}
      ></TextInput>
      <button type="submit" className="btn btn-primary">
        Save
      </button>
      <button onClick={onCancel} className="btn btn-danger ml-2">
        Cancel
      </button>
    </form>
  );
}
```

From what I've read in the docs, you do not have to wrap anything inside `act(...)` if you use `waitForElement()` with the react-testing-library, it does it for you. I have also tried every possible way of wrapping different snippets in `act(...)` using await in every possible way. Either the test fails because of a `TimeoutSession`, or because of a misuse of `Promise`

I'm new to react and react testing. I just want to make sure I haven't misunderstood anything fundamental. I find the whole `await act(...)` thing very confusing

Comment: Your understanding seems correct and I can't find anything wrong with your code. 

Make sure there isn't any other state updates you have missed. Besides the `errorMessage` is there anything else you need to wait for?

Comment: No, just the `errorMessage` I'll check for any other states. Thanks for you answer :)

Comment: Are you perhaps using any kind of animation to display `errorMessage` temporarily, something like a Toast component? If so, you might be getting this error because you are updating the state to make the error message disappear after the test is completed. In which case you need to wait for the message to appear *and* disappear in your tests.

Comment: No, no animation whatsoever...

Answer (score 0):

I stumbled upon this question when looking for an answer to the same question. Therefore, adding my answer here so it might help someone.

Some background info if you find the whole `await act(...)` thing very confusing:

1. The [`act()`](https://github.com/reactwg/react-18/discussions/102) test helper was intended to make sure all updates related to the triggered interactions like button click are processed and applied to the DOM.
2. [React Testing Library](https://testing-library.com/docs/react-testing-library/intro/) helper functions already wrap `act()`. Therefore, if you use them, you do not have to use `act()` in your tests.

However, even if you use the React Testing Library, you might get this warning in your tests in situations like the test case times out or exits before the (mocked) API response is processed by the component.

Whenever I got this warning, I was able to resolve it using the following approach:

1. When mocking API calls, Jest `mockImplementation()` works better than `mockResolvedValue()` and `mockRejectedValue()`.

Therefore, instead of

```js
jest.fn().mockRejectedValue(new Error(errorMessage))
```

do

```js
jest.fn().mockImplementation(() => Promise.reject(errorMessage))
```

2. Use Testing Library [`findBy...`](https://testing-library.com/docs/dom-testing-library/api-async#findby-queries) queries instead of `getBy...` while awaiting API calls to resolve/reject.

Therefore, instead of

```js
await waitFor(() => getByText(errorMessage));
```

do

```js
await screen.findByText(errorMessage);
```

Hope this helps. Happy testing :-)